# Will I lose my files when I replace my Windows OS with Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows

Will I lose my **files** when I replace my *Windows OS* with *Ubuntu*?

Comment: your replacing the whole OS - including files - so yes it'll all disappear....

Comment: But you have it all backed up right?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you will lose your files if you replace Windows OS with Ubuntu.
- For that, install Ubuntu on a separate partition other than the partition where Windows is installed.

Comment: you dont need to buy a external hard-drive.How many partitions are there in your internal hard-disk.

Answer (score 0):

In case your window partition map is set up to have a separate partition for your files and documentation you can install Ubuntu (alongside or replace windows) and  during installation, GUI will offer to import existing files and document from windows. Of course backup of your files and  documents is quite important and somehow a must when playing with installation, partition etc. I personally hold at least two separate backups of all my digital stuff.